# Clip lines by overlapping polygons

Tags: polygon, clip, line

I want to cut a line shape into parts by polygon areas. No problem so far. But the polygons overlaps each other at the border. I need one line result for the whole area of every polygon. Any ideas for an automatic solution? Gdal ogr can't do it because of self intersecting polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is a GRASS GIS [v.select](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/v.select.html) iteration. So I get full line-shapes for each polygon, without getting self-intersection problems.

Comment: How exactly this should work? I have lines which intersects/crosses polygons and whatever I do - intersects, overlay etc. I never get lines clipped to polygons. And with basic clip under Vector menu I get only one line for all touching/overlapping polygons.